# Insert new Dictionary entries of <UserStatus (enum), IEnumerable<string>> into different keys

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, object

we are doing the following programming exercise: [Who's Online](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5b6375f707a2664ada00002a).

We have written the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Kata
{
  public static Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>> WhosOnline /*❓❓*/ (User[] friends)
  {
    var users = new Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>>(); //We will save each friends' status and name
    for(int i=0; i<friends.Length; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(friends[i].Username+","+friends[i].Status+","+friends[i].LastActivity);
      if(friends[i].Status==UserStatus.Online && friends[i].LastActivity>10){  //If it was active more than 10 minutes ago, it is away
        friends[i].Status=UserStatus.Away;  
      }

      users.Add(friends[i].Status, new []{friends[i].Username});  //We need to store the userStatus and its name

      //users[friends[i].Status] = new []{friends[i].Username};
    }

    return users;
  }
}
```

Being the tests:

```
namespace Solution 
{
  using NUnit.Framework;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  [TestFixture]
  public class SampleTest
  {
    [Test, Description("Example test two of each")]
    public void SoloTest()
    {
      User[] friends = new User[] 
      {
        new User("David", UserStatus.Online, 10),
        new User("Anna", UserStatus.Online, 1),
        new User("Lucy", UserStatus.Offline, 22),
        new User("Viviana", UserStatus.Offline, 44),
        new User("Bob", UserStatus.Online, 104),
        new User("Fina", UserStatus.Online, 300),
      };
      var expected = new Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>>
      {
        {UserStatus.Online, new[] {"David"}},
        {UserStatus.Online, new[] {"Anna"}},
        {UserStatus.Offline, new[] {"Lucy"}},
        {UserStatus.Offline, new[] {"Viviana"}},
        {UserStatus.Away, new[] {"Bob"}},
        {UserStatus.Away, new[] {"Fina"}}
      };
      Assert.That(Kata.WhosOnline(friends), Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }

    [Test, Description("Example test no one online")]
    public void NoOnlineTest()
    {
      User[] friends = new User[] 
      {
        new User("Lucy", UserStatus.Offline, 22),
        new User("Bob", UserStatus.Online, 104)
      };
      var expected = new Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>>
      {
        {UserStatus.Offline, new[] {"Lucy"}},
        {UserStatus.Away, new[] {"Bob"}}
      };
      Assert.That(Kata.WhosOnline(friends), Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
  }
}
```

We found that it outputs:

```
System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Online
```

We have identified that it is produced because of in the line 16:

```
  users.Add(friends[i].Status, new []{friends[i].Username});  //We need to store the userStatus and its name
```

We are trying to assign a Dictionary entry, which key has been already inserted.

We would need to do something like the following:

```
users.Add(i, {friends[i].Status, new []{friends[i].Username}});  //We need to store the userStatus and its name
```

Adding to the dictionary each entry with a unique key. However if we execute the code with the previous line we get:

```
src/Solution.cs(17,20): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '{'
```

And if we execute it as follows:

```
  users.Add(i, friends[i].Status, new []{friends[i].Username});  //We need to store the userStatus and its name
```

We observe:

```
src/Solution.cs(17,13): error CS1501: No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments
```

In addition we also have tried to store entries like:

```
users[friends[i].Status] = new []{friends[i].Username};
```

However, it produces the same output:

```
System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Online
```

Besides, we have adapted it as:

```
  users[i] = (friends[i].Status,new []{friends[i].Username});
```

After that, we get:

```
src/Solution.cs(20,13): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'UserStatus'
```

How could we insert new entries of UserStatus, IEnumerable, with unique keys?

We have read:

- [printing all contents of array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265247/printing-all-contents-of-array-in-c-sharp)
- [Different ways of adding to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838476/different-ways-of-adding-to-dictionary)
- [Dictionary with object as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321235/dictionary-with-object-as-value)
- [C# appending Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917625/c-sharp-appending-dictionary)
- [Adding an item to a dictionary as the first item c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040733/adding-an-item-to-a-dictionary-as-the-first-item-c-sharp)
- [Adding a dictionary element at a specific place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918328/adding-a-dictionary-element-at-a-specific-place)
- [How to insert element in first index in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761109/how-to-insert-element-in-first-index-in-dictionary)
- [C# Add elements to Dictionary with key as string and value as another Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276015/c-sharp-add-elements-to-dictionary-with-key-as-string-and-value-as-another-dicti)

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Guru Stron we have written the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Kata
{
  public static Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>> WhosOnline /*❓❓*/ (User[] friends)
  {
    var users = new Dictionary<UserStatus, List<string>>(); //We will save each friends' status and name
    for(int i=0; i<friends.Length; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(friends[i].Username+","+friends[i].Status+","+friends[i].LastActivity);
      if(friends[i].Status==UserStatus.Online && friends[i].LastActivity>10){  //If it was active more than 10 minutes ago, it is away
        friends[i].Status=UserStatus.Away;  
      }

      if(!users.ContainsKey(friends[i].Status)){  //-> We should check if this status has already been saved
        users.Add(friends[i].Status, new List<string>{friends[i].Username});
      }else{
        users[friends[i].Status].Add(friends[i].Username);
      }

    }


    return users;
  }
}
```

However console writes:

```
src/Solution.cs(25,12): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<UserStatus, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<UserStatus, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>'
```

Because of we are trying to save a List inside a dictionary which has been declared as IEnumerable, and we can not change its type.

Then we tried, to convert it back to IEnumerable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Kata
{
  public static Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>> WhosOnline /*❓❓*/ (User[] friends)
  {
    var users = new Dictionary<UserStatus, List<string>>(); //We will save each friends' status and name
    for(int i=0; i<friends.Length; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(friends[i].Username+","+friends[i].Status+","+friends[i].LastActivity);
      if(friends[i].Status==UserStatus.Online && friends[i].LastActivity>10){  //If it was active more than 10 minutes ago, it is away
        friends[i].Status=UserStatus.Away;  
      }

      if(!users.ContainsKey(friends[i].Status)){
        users.Add(friends[i].Status, new List<string>{friends[i].Username});
      }else{
        users[friends[i].Status].Add(friends[i].Username);
      }

    }

    var output = new Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>>();  //We try to convert List<string> back to IEnumerable<string>
    foreach(KeyValuePair<UserStatus, List<string>> entry in users){
      if(!output.ContainsKey(entry.Key)){
        output.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value.ToArray());
      }else{
        users[entry.Key].Add(entry.Value.ToArray());
      }    
    }

    return output;
  }
}
```

And we observe:

```
src/Solution.cs(29,30): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
```

After that, we followed the suggestion made by @Guru Stron and we started to use **Linq** as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Kata
{
  public static Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>> WhosOnline /*❓❓*/ (User[] friends)
  {
    /*How could we express: if(f.Status==Online && f.LastActivity > 10) f.Status=Away ❗❓*/
    var users = friends.GroupBy(f => f.Status).ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
        g => (IEnumerable<string>)(g.Select(f => f.Username).ToList()));

    foreach(KeyValuePair<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>> entry in users)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Status: "+entry.Key+" Username: ");
      Console.WriteLine("[{0}]",string.Join(", ",entry.Value));
    }

    return users;
  }
}
```

However, the tests fail because of we would need to express:

```
if(f.Status==Online && f.LastActivity > 10) f.Status=Away
```

How could do it with Linq?

Comment: Your test case is wrong too, it's adding the same key to `expected`

Comment: Shouldn't it be, in example for `Online`, this : `{ UserStatus.Online, new[] { "David", "Anna" } }` ?

Answer (score 1):

[Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) in C# is collection of unique keys and values associated with them.

So first of all you will want `Dictionary<UserStatus, List<string>>()` not `Dictionary<UserStatus, IEnumerable<string>>()`(for convenience). Secondary when adding a user to status group(key) you need to check if such group(key) exists and if yes - add to it, if not - add it:

```
if(!users.ContainsKey(friends[i].Status))
{
    users.Add(friends[i].Status, new List<string>{friends[i].Username})
}
else
{
    users[friends[i].Status].Add(friends[i].Username);
}
```

and lastly you can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

```
var users = friends.GroupBy(f => f.Status)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(f => f.UserName).ToList())
```

If you can't change signature of the your function LINQ would be more convenient cause you can do

```
var users = friends.GroupBy(f => f.Status)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
        g => (IEnumerable<string>)(g.Select(f => f.UserName).ToList()))
```